# How do I test (use) Facebook sharing plugin in localhost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

SO. Currently I am developing a Facebook application like www.meaww.com. I have two queries.

**1st.** How can I run Facebook sharing [plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) in a localhost environment to test whether my web application content is properly shared or not? Right now when I use the localhost URL, while sharing I get the facebook share dialog with an error "Something went wrong, please try again."

**2nd.** If you ever had played a test on Meaww it renders the result in an image. Which makes facebook sharing quite easy. Is there any similar way so I can wrap or render my result view in an image with C#?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: 1: Facebook of course need to be able to hit your URL to test it. 2. Yes you can generate an image too

Comment: What do you suggest for the first query? and can you please give a hint or provide me with some tutorial with rendering views in image state?

Comment: Make the URL publicly available. Search Google for generate image in C#

Answer (score -1):

maybe a local server? heres a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCHzlUiDD10